# I'm trying to include simplepeer.js, but its showing 404 error not found. Instead I'm giving right path

Tags: javascript, html, express, directory, simple-peer

**Folder Structure**

[image: Folder Structure]

express to access static file.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))
```

In index.html

```
<script src="/simple-peer/simplepeer.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: You don't appear to have a folder `simple-peer` under `public`.

Comment: I need to get it from node modules, if I'm trying ../node_modules/simple-peer/simple-peer.min.js, then too it's not working

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the way you've done it overrides the default process of finding files. Adding the line `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/node_modules"))` after your existing `app.use` may fix it.

Comment: Thanks alot it worki